# What spell did Dumbledore use against Voldemort in the Ministry of Magic?

Tags: harry-potter

In the *Order of the Phoenix*, Dumbledore uses a spell against Voldemort.

The following dialogue ensues:

> **Voldemort:** "You do not seek to kill me, Dumbledore? Above such brutality, are you?"
>   **Dumbledore:** "We both know there are other ways of destroying a man, Tom. Merely taking your life would not satisfy me, I admit."

I know that someone asked the question to JKR, but she refused to answer as it could spoil book 7. Any idea on what it might be?

Comment: Impotense sexualis! This also explains why Voldemort seemed so frustrated in the later books.

Comment: It's not in the book and, apparently, J.K. Rowling refused to answer which spell Dumbledore used against Voldemort at the Ministry of Magic. I would guess it might be a spell that caused Voldemort to feel remorse which, because of his fractured soul, would have been so painful it might have caused Voldemort's death (if there weren't the Horcruxes). But like a love potion cannot create true love, could magic create true remorse? Probably not. But remorse is the thing I see as possibly breaking Voldemort. Just a comment because I think it's not provable, and just a thought on my part.

Comment: @ASlytherin You should put that comment as an answer.

Comment: Whatever it was, it seemed very powerful; From just before your quote: "The spell, whatever it was, caused no visible damage to the shield,
though a deep, gonglike note reverberated from it, an oddly chilling
sound. . . ." *Harry Potter and the Order of the Phoenix - The Only One He Ever Feared*

Comment: If anyone ever finds out, I'd love to know! Book 7 has long since been released, you'd think JK could give us an answer *now*.

Comment: I think it may simply been some sort of immobilizing spell (or similar) just so the good guys could escape. Dumbledore would not want to take Voldy's life because they needed to destroy the cruxes... hence the "other ways of destroying a man" and "would not satisfy me" because Dumby knew just killing Voldy on the spot wouldn't really kill him.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Copy-pasting ASlytherin:

> It's not in the book and, apparently, J.K. Rowling refused to answer which spell Dumbledore used against Voldemort at the Ministry of Magic. I would guess it might be a spell that caused Voldemort to feel remorse which, because of his fractured soul, would have been so painful it might have caused Voldemort's death (if there weren't the Horcruxes). But like a love potion cannot create true love, could magic create true remorse? Probably not. But remorse is the thing I see as possibly breaking Voldemort. Just a comment because I think it's not provable, and just a thought on my part. –

Answer (score 13):

Since Rowling has refused to answer this question in interviews, the only thing that can be determined is that Dumbledore's spell is non-lethal. Of course, that description runs the gamut of anything from Tickling Charms to even the Cruciatus (which causes pain but not death). Even then, the list changes depending on circumstance: Levitation charms generally aren't lethal, but a drop on the head or a hundred-foot fall could easily spell someone's doom).

From what we can determine, the spell was not the Disarming Charm or Stunning Curse (as those spells have reddish tinges to them), nor was it the purplish-flame that Dolohov cast, since that spell also has a distinct appearance. Neither Levicorpus nor *Alohomora* have spell trails (and frankly, *Alohomora* makes little to no sense in this situation). What I am getting at is that we can only remove spells from the "possible spell that Dumbledore cast" list and since we do not have an exhaustive list of every spell in the Harry Potter universe, we can't definitively determine what the spell was.

Any further speculation on what Dumbledore's spell was is just that: speculation.

Comment: Alohomora - unlock his heart?

Answer (score 0):

I think that the spell would have done something like the Dementor's  Kiss- it would have destroyed the portion of soul inside Voldemort's body. Dumbledore implies that the spell is worse than death and it fits with his statements in the third and fourth books that this fate is much, much worse than death. Also, the gong is "oddly chilling"- similar to the effect that dementors have on people.

Comment: The question was what spell he used, not what it did.

Comment: I know, but as we don't know the incantation for the spell it's defined by what it would have done.

Comment: @phantom42 Surely a spell can be defined by what it does?